# Using an alias to call a python script

Tags: bash, cygwin, alias

In order to use a python script that is a part of a molecular docking software I have to use a python shell included in the software files.
This means that I have to write

```
pythonsh path/path/script.py parameters
```

I have tried setting an alias for path/path/script.py in order to call it quicker but bash fails to recognize my alias when it is a part of something like this.

Is there a way to do this?

Note: I'm using cygwin on windows. I don't think this will have any repercussions on the answer (bash is bash right?) but I thought I should  disclose that information just in case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just alias the whole thing

```
alias pshell="pythonsh path/path/script.py"
```

Or use a function

```
pshell() {
  pythonsh path/path/script.py "$@"
}
```

Alternatively you could set a variable for the path in a source file, and then use the variable in-line, e.g. in your `~/.bashrc`

```
pyth="path/path/script.py"
```

And now you could run it with

```
pythonsh $pyth parameters
```

Note, if the path has a space or escape characters, make sure to quote `"$pyth"`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the correction. I usually export them to reuse them in scripts, but not needed here so updated answer.

Comment: I tried adding this to my .bashrc preprec="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py"  The problem is, when I use pythonsh $preprec the file path stops at Program\ and it prints that no such file exists

Comment: @user22277 You will need to quote the variable when you use it if it has a space, to prevent bash from word-splitting on it. So do  `pythonsh "$preprec"`

Comment: If I use quotes I get C:\Program Files\MGLTools-1.5.6\pythonsh.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory although the file exists.

Comment: @user22277 Try removing the escape in the path, so do `preprec='/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_recepto‌​r4.py'`

Comment: C:\Program Files\MGLTools-1.5.6\pythonsh.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MGLTools-1.5.6/Lib/site-packages/AutoDockTools/Utilities24/prepare_receptor4.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Something bizarre is going on. If I try to use the script with pythonsh wholepath/script.py it still doesn't see it. However, if I move to the folder and run pythonsh script.py it works. I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @user22277 Weird, no idea what's going on, unless it's something `pythonsh` specific. You should still be able to use an alias or a function though, which will save even more typing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a shell function and include it in your `.bashrc` or `_bashrc` in your case as you are using Cygwin. It would look something like this:

```
function wobble {
    pythonsh path/path/script.py $@
}
```

You can use the function as if it were an alias: `wobble parameters`